# How to include DLL from another directory

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

I have made a dll by the name `test.dll`.
I have the .lib file and the header file for the same.

I pasted the `.lib` file and a header file in program A and program B folder, but I want to have a common folder, where I can paste my `test.dll`, so that both A and B can use it.

I am using VS 2008. Language is C++

Comment: I haven't done Windows programming in a long time. You need to set an environment variable. It's got a name like load library path; you might even see it if you go into Visual Studio's settings for environment variables. You should even be able to debug the source.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus i have tried that in that i gave the path as c:\Newfolder\test.dll but when i compile it gives me a error about dll missing

Comment: you could dynamically load the DLL via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: This is why I didn't "answer" answer your question. As I can see, the common directory should be in your PATH. The LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress isn't a bad way to go either, as I recall (from eight years ago).

Comment: It's rather painful to do this. Your practical options are 1. Add the DLL directory to the `PATH` environment variable (very draconian solution, I would not do it this way) or 2. Put the DLL in the same directory as the executable (I always prefer this way).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the common directory to your PATH, or start both A & B from the same directory (which would also contain the DLL).

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details/options...

-- More --

By default, the system will look in the following locations...

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The system directory.
3. The 16-bit system directory.
4. The Windows directory.
5. The current directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

You can't change them programably, but you can get the result you want by adding the common folder location to your PATH environment variable before running the programs

Comment: i have read the article but could not understand anything please if you could tell me how to do it

Comment: @hardyz009: Just read it again ... ;-) - anyway do as Gwyn told you regarding adding the path to the DLL to the PATH environment variable, this will do the job.

Comment: @gw so my environment variable currently is c:\NewFolder\test.dll
what should i change it to

Comment: don't include the file name in the path. `C:\NewFolder` is what you want in this case. Make sure it is *part of* the PATH environment variable; you don't want to replace everything else, just add this to it.

Comment: You need your PATH variable to include c:\NewFolder\
see http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: @GwynEvans in my project properties in the debugging tab in the environment variable my path is C:\NewFolder\ but still sayin dll missing .Am i putting the path in the right tab or not??

Comment: @GwynEvans You *can* change the search path programmatically - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh310513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - on at least windows 7. It's a bit complicated though.

Comment: What is the difference between 1. and 5. (directory from which the application loaded and current directory) ?